# Formatting the thread call stack

Tags: formatting, sourcecode

Given a thread call stack as follows:

```
FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.setCapacity(Text.java:240)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:204) 
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:194) 
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.<init>(Text.java:86)
......
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.RowContainer.next(RowContainer.java:263)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.Row Container.next(RowContainer.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.checkAndGenObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:823)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JoinOperator.endGroup(JoinOperator.java:263)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:198)
......
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.RowContainer.nextBlock(RowContainer.java:397)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
```

How to write the latex code to achieve the following effect. The effects contains Indentation, Automatic bold for specific lines and A monospaced font. Note that the generated lines should be able to span the two columns if the paper is two-column style. I've tried lstlisting but the fonts and indentation are not good.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in what the abstract problem (“the following effect”) is? Just two-column text? Indentation? Automatic bold for specific lines? A monospaced font? The footnotes? What have you tried, what didn’t work?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: @LijieXu You can set the style of fonts and indent in `lstlisting` environment by `\lstset` provided by package `listings`.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to get bold face without marking it up (on the other hand, I don't understand when boldface is selected). Here's a way to get what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newenvironment{javaerror}
 {\ttfamily\list{}{\leftmargin=1em\itemindent=-1em\parsep=\parskip}%
  \catcode`\.=\active
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\.
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\penalty0 }%
  \obeylines\raggedright\item\relax}
 {\endlist}

\begin{document}
Some text before the error messages
some text before the error messages
some text before the error messages
\begin{javaerror}
FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
\textbf{Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space}
\textbf{org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.setCapacity(Text.java:240)}
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:204) 
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:194) 
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.<init>(Text.java:86)
......
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.RowContainer.next(RowContainer.java:263)
\textbf{org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.Row Container.next(RowContainer.java:74)}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.checkAndGenObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:823)
\textbf{at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JoinOperator.endGroup(JoinOperator.java:263)}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:198)
......
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.RowContainer.nextBlock(RowContainer.java:397)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
\end{javaerror}
\end{document}
```

[image]